# ITerm2 Console connection to Cisco equipment Control-A does not work

Tags: macos, iterm

I connect to Cisco Equipment via console cable and am currently trying to use ITerm2.

The problem is I cannot get the Control-A (Move to beginning of line) command to work.  I've tried to add in the hex code ^a with 0x01  with no luck..

Funny thing is..  Control-A works as expected if I am in ITerm2 and:

- Am browsing my local drive / directories
- Connected to Cisco equipment via telnet or SSH

I only see Control-A NOT work if I'm connected via the console cable.  The Control-E (Move to end), Control-U(Delete line) always work as expected though regardless if I'm connected via console or other remote access.

Anybody have any thoughts on what I can change to get this one function working.

I am running the below command when loading my cisco profile:

screen /dev/cu.usbserial-A9030WJK  -f 9600,cs8,-parenb,-cstopb,-hupcl

USB to Ethernet cable, I am not using the usb -> serial adapter and I'm using a 13" MBA laptop El Cap.

Comment: Does it work with Terminal.app ?

Comment: @Mark
<ul>
- Terminal Console Connect to Router:  NO  
 - Terminal ssh to Router:  yes  
 - Console connection to Router -> ssh to another router:  no  
 - SSH from OS X (using ITerm) to Router (Same physical devicde as above):  yes

Comment: updated ITERM to 3.0.2..  now Control-A works as expected when SSH'd into a cisco router.

Answer (score 1):

updated ITERM to 3.0.2.. now Control-A works as expected when SSH'd into a cisco router. –